# Jetpack Compose TextField arguments list; color not allowed

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

For some reason when trying to make a TextField in Compose I am constantly running into problems with the parameters, for intance:

```
// this is perfectly fine
@Composable
fun Username() {
val emailState = remember{ mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())}
TextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.username_label))},
    value = emailState.value,
    onValueChange = { emailState.value = it },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email),
    )
}
```

if i try to insert a colours value however, everything falls apart:

```
@Composable
fun Username() {
val emailState = remember{ mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())}
TextField(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    label = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.username_label))},
    value = emailState.value,
    onValueChange = { emailState.value = it },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email),
    color = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        )
    )
}
```

regardless of where I add 'color' within the arguments list here it won't work.
I get back this:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
```

I don't understand the Constructor here at all, I have even changed my code to be more similar to others online and still get the same error.

Compose version is 1.0.2

Comment: it's `colors`, not `color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextField has no `color` parameter.
you must use `colors` instead